# iOS App - No functionality when offline

Tags: ios, offline

I'm writing a native iOS app that pulls all it's content from the internet. So, when the app's offline, there's not really any functionality that the app has. I have two questions:

1. Will Apple approve of an app where there really is no offline mode? My app won't cache data or anything. Basically, if the app is offline, there will be a message displaying that the app requires an internet connection.
2. If so, how do I display an image if the app is offline saying that the app requires an internet connection. Right now, the app just crashes if it can't reach a connection.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the Reachability library available [here](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability), just follow the examples described in the README.md file, it's pretty straightforward.

Basically, after you've set up the library and the required framework (SystemConfiguration.framework), you can import Reachability into your view controller's classes and do something like this:

```
Reachability* reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];
reach.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
{
    // Your app has internet connection, begin working as usual
};

reach.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
{
    // Your app does not have internet connection, 
    // display an alert/image that will notify the user about this
};

[reach startNotifier];
```

You could put this code into the viewDidLoad: method, so when the app runs it checks for internet connection and does something based on whether it's available or not.

I think that Apple will approve the app, because there are a lot of apps that require a internet connection to do anything. A good thing that you could do is that you could save the data when user is done working with the app, so that when the user runs the app tomorrow let's say, and has no internet connection, he at least could look at his work he's done. A good example of this is the WordPress app, if you don't have any connection at the moment but you've logged in recently, you can see your older posts, but can't post anything new because you don't have the connection available.

Hope it helps.